# PHP - How to dynamically input multi-dimensional arrays only knowing the keys?

Tags: php, arrays, class, instance, key-value

I have a multi-dimensional array with key value pairs. Some of the values of the keys are arrays, and some of the values in that array are arrays as well. It is only 3 branches deep (for now), but I am trying to recursively loop through the array, save the key for each level of the branch, and create a new array when it reaches a string that also mimics the structure of the original array. When it reaches a string, there should be a new object instantiation for each value.

The code below sort of does this, but only creates a flat array.

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
if (!is_array($value)) {
    $a_objects[$key] = new Component([$key], $value);
} else {
    foreach ($value as $valueKey => $valueValue) {
        if (!is_array($valueValue)) {
            $a_objects[$key . "_" . $valueKey] = new Component([$key, $valueKey], $valueValue);
        } else {
            foreach ($valueValue as $k => $v) {
                $a_objects[$key . "_" . $valueKey . "_" . $k] = new Component([$key, $valueKey, $k], $v);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my own best attempt at this but it does not seem to save into the b_objects after some testing it does not seem to be saving the object instances.

```
$b_objects = [];
function create_r($data, $id)
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value) == true) {

            array_push($id, $key);
            create_r($value, $id);
        } else {

            array_push($id, $key);

            $b_objects[$key] = new Component($id, $value);
            $id = [];
        }
    }
}

$id = [];
create_r($data, $id);

echo "this is b_objects";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($b_objects);
echo "</pre>";
```

I verified that $id array contains the right "keys". I feel like this solution is pretty close but I have no idea how to use my $id array to mimic the structure of the $data.

I want to be able to say $b_objects[$level1key][$level2key][$level3key]...[$leveln-1key] = new Component...

Thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? seem silly to initialize everything when you could use autoloading as it's traversed though when you actually access it, using __get and __call

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you pass `$b_objects` by reference to your `create_r()` function. Otherwise each function call will instantiate a new `$b_objects` variable which is not used anywhere in the code afterwards.

Passing by reference allows the function to actually change the input array. Notice the `&` sign in the function declaration.

```
function create_r($data, $id, &$res)
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value) == true) {

            array_push($id, $key);
            create_r($value, $id, $res);
        } else {

            array_push($id, $key);

            $res[$key] = new Component($id, $value);
            $id = [];
        }
    }
}

$id = [];
$b_objects = [];
create_r($data, $id, $b_objects);
```